# fadeout text-color (pure-css)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the effect which can be seen [here](http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/353/d/d/googlemusik__google_music___grooveshark_by_illusionmist-d4jkkny.png) in the lower right where the artist name and track title fade out to the right.

My first attempt was creating an overlay image, but this resulted in an ugly edge on the right because the colors would add. (maybe I can substract the images before using them?)
([this](http://s14.postimage.org/6ghvkv019/overflow.png) is how it looks like)

Then I searched for a CSS 3 attribute which is crossbrowser compatible. But I didn't even found a solution that works with all modern browsers.

EDIT: I am not searching for an animation. I want to have a gradient.

This seems to be very difficult to explain. I made a fiddle of how far I got: http://jsfiddle.net/z7cK2/

ANSWER: OUCH, nevermind...
is seemed I just used an old image m(

Comment: Can you look at the source of Google Music to see how they did it?

Comment: i have checked it your fiddle example its working fine on all modern browers....

Answer (score 6):

What kind of image did you try to overlay?

**Method 1 (Image):**

http://jsfiddle.net/R3ndb/2/

Use an absolute positioned image as an overlay.

**Method 2 (CSS3 gradient):**

http://jsfiddle.net/R3ndb/3/

Use an overlayed DIV with a CSS3 gradient.

Comment: 1. It's an image - it doesn't really have sth. to do with Google music // 2. I don't want an animation.

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood you. I think you need to overlay an image. what exactly did you try?

Comment: I exactly did that but my background color is not 100% black and it is an gradient (from top to bottom). So if those two gray colors overlap they became darker and result in an edge (see [here](http://s14.postimage.org/6ghvkv019/overflow.png))

Comment: added a fiddle to make this easier to understand :)